# convert from PCS: Palestine 1923 Palestine Grid to WGS84 coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, palestine

I have the coordinate system of points in GIS in PCS: Palestine 1923 Palestine Grid, is it possible to convert the coordinate system to WGS84 coordinate system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it’s possible to do that, all you need is to use project (data management) tool then to choose the WGS1984 but be careful to use the appropriate transformation to transform your points accurately

[image]